# what is it" same network meta-analysis object is used for arguments x and y" from netleague order?

Tags: r

If the same network meta-analysis object is used for arguments x and y, reciprocal treatment estimates will be shown in the upper triangle

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/netmeta/html/netleague.html

I really cannot understand and I wanna show reciprocal treatment estimates in the upper triangle

Comment: Hi Panitana Pithaka, welcome to SO. It is important to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Also include an example of the result you are getting, and the desired result. Thanks